# Image upload does not work with Volley request to php using $_FILES and move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am having difficulty to store image data to the database, I have tried two methods, the first one is working, but the second method is not working which I actually want to use.

Working code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $id = 86;

    $path = "uploads/$id.jpg";

    $sql = "UPDATE user SET imagePath = '$imagename' where id = '$id'";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
     }

    mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

However the following code does not work. I use the same logic but this time use `$_FILES` and `move_uploaded_file`. I get to the point echo "Successfully Uploaded" but the image is not saved to the uploads folder.

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        $name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $temp_name=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];

        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        $id = 96;

        $imagename=$id."_".time().$file_name;           
        $path = "uploads/".$imagename.".png";

        $sql = "UPDATE user SET imagePath = '$imagename' where id = '$id'";
        $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
            echo "Successfully Uploaded";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Update: Here is how this is called from android:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    //Converting Bitmap to String
    String image = getStringImage(((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

    //Getting Image Name
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating parameters
    Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    //Adding parameters
    params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

    //returning parameters
    return params;
}
```

Update 2: The bitmap image is encoded to Base64 as below.

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

The `KEY_NAME` in params is equal `"name"`.

Comment: Are you sure that the _working code_ actually works. I would bet it does not.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I tested again and I am positive that the first code works.

Comment: Then show the HTML for the form that activates this pieces of PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I have added the android (java) code that fills the parameters to be posted. I use Volley for request.

Answer (score 0):

If it says "Successfully Uploaded" the connection is done and the update, but the problem should be here

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

you probabily didn't call as "name" in the input, i mean here `<input type='file' name='xxxxx'/>` 
you shoul try

```
$name=$_FILES["image"]["xxxxx"];
```

Comment: You are probably right about the method call: move_uploaded_file, On the other hand the The `KEY_NAME` in params is equal to `"name"`.